# How do two devices communicate on IBM-Watson platform

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-iot

On Watson MQTT foundation, how do I publish a message from one device (`publish-"iot-2/evt/xxxxxxxxx"`) to another device (`subscribe-"iot-2/cmd/xxxxxxxx"`)?

How is this possible as devices' publish and subscribe topics cannot be same? Is it possible without first receiving it in an application and republish to 2nd device, or devices can only send/receive data to/from an application?

Is this Watson implementation or MQTT spec?

Answer (score 1):

Devices publish events and subscribe to commands. An application can send commands to a device.

A device can not send commands to another device.
The Watson IoT platform has specific topic strings, refer to [documentation.](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/devices/mqtt.html)

If you have a device such as a raspberry pi sending commands, have you tried connecting it as an application to publish the command and then have the other device connect as device to subscribe and receive the commmand?